# dual monitor not working

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, dual-graphics

I tried to connect a second monitor over HDMI (my laptop has not VGA) and it is not detected. I tried with the live version and it works.

Hypothesis: a missing package or a something in a configuration file.

Ubuntu 20.04, Dell xps l502x with Nvidia Geforce 525 M and Intel HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2) (with optimus).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. After some temptatives and problems with Nvidia proprietary drivers I reinstalled the system with Nouveau driver. And it works. To use the audio just use

```
pavucontrol
```

Comment: Sorry for ask, but you just reinstalled Ubuntu with Nouveau Drivers? I have the same problem.